# телеграм бот на питоне, воспринимает первое условие за ответ хотя нужно второе условие

Tags: python-3.x

Привет читавшим это жалкое смс, короче помогите, пишу телеграм бота на python3 и мне нужно когда юзер вводит команду(можно и строка) бот выводит смс "играем сулифа" и после смс бота юзер должен вести "камень" or "ножницы" or "бумага"и после этого бот рандомно выбирает ответ ну тип если 1 бот кидает "бумага" или что то другое заранее спасибо thank you very mach[image: это кусочек кода в котором проблема]

Comment: Кажется этот вопрос с or-ами уже 100500-й тут, регулярно их задают

Comment: Мой stackoverflow бот на питоне автоматически минусует вопрос, где код приложен изображением.

Answer (score 1):

```
if message.text == 'бумага' or message.text == 'камень' or message.text == 'ножницы':
```

или так:

```
if message.text in ['бумага', 'камень', 'ножницы']:
```

И действия после проверки этого условия и само условие должны быть сдвинуты влево на один таб

Answer (score 1):

Так все верно!

Вы же не запрашиваете ответа от юзера, поэтому так и происходит.

Вы используйте один message.text для двух проверок.

В этой библиотеке (если это telebot) переназначение на другую функцию  производится вот так:

```
 bot.register_next_step_handler(message, function)
```

message - Ваша сущность "message";

function - это функция, что будет обрабатывать новые данные.

Comment: оу май тогда как сделать чтоб message.text использовался как ответ юзера кстать это все в функции и как помять на один там в лево если он не будет относиться к /game